GeForce GTX 1060 video decoder for Epiphany
I am trying to enjoy fullscreen 1440 VP9 YouTube videos in GNOME Web (Epiphany) on GeForce GTX 1060, but, after installing the proprietary driver, the videos consistently drop a lot of frames and are distractingly and unpleasantly not smooth as if lacking computing resources. How do I further investigate the issue to make the videos smooth?
I know that it should work because the same video plays perfectly in Totem (after applying a workaround for an unrelated issue), which relies on GStreamer similar to Epiphany. Even Firefox handles it somehow.
Here is the configuration after the instructions were applied for Debian "Sid" per the wiki page "NVIDIA Proprietary Driver".
$ uname -a
Linux debian 6.11.2-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.11.2-1 (2024-10-05) x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ lspci -nn | egrep -i "3d|display|vga"
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] [10de:1c02] (rev a1)
$ nvidia-detect
Detected NVIDIA GPUs:
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] [10de:1c02] (rev a1)

Checking card:  NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] (rev a1)
Your card is supported by all driver versions.
Your card is also supported by the Tesla 470 drivers series.
It is recommended to install the
    nvidia-driver
package.
$ apt list linux-headers-amd64 nvidia-driver firmware-misc-nonfree nvidia-cuda-dev nvidia-cuda-toolkit
firmware-misc-nonfree/unstable,now 20240909-1 all [installed]
linux-headers-amd64/unstable,now 6.11.2-1 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-cuda-dev/unstable,now 12.1.105~12.1.1-4 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-cuda-toolkit/unstable,now 12.1.105~12.1.1-4 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-driver/unstable,now 535.183.06-1 amd64 [installed]
$ cat /etc/default/grub.d/nvidia-modeset.cfg
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX nvidia-drm.modeset=1"
$ systemctl status nvidia-suspend.service
○ nvidia-suspend.service - NVIDIA system suspend actions
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nvidia-suspend.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
$ systemctl status nvidia-hibernate.service
○ nvidia-hibernate.service - NVIDIA system hibernate actions
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nvidia-hibernate.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
$ systemctl status nvidia-resume.service
○ nvidia-resume.service - NVIDIA system resume actions
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nvidia-resume.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
$ cat /proc/driver/nvidia/params | grep PreserveVideoMemoryAllocations
PreserveVideoMemoryAllocations: 1
$ eglinfo -B -p wayland | grep renderer
OpenGL core profile renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL compatibility profile renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL ES profile renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB/PCIe/SSE2


According to another wiki page, Web should perform hardware acceleration with VDPAU. The hardware acceleration in the browser settings is enabled. The card supports decoding VP9.
$ apt list nvidia-vdpau-driver gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad/unstable,now 1.24.8-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-vdpau-driver/unstable,now 535.183.06-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
$ ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau | grep nvidia
libvdpau_nvidia.so.1
$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep VDPAU\ driver
[   163.063] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
$ gst-inspect-1.0 nvcodec | grep VP9
  nvvp9dec: NVDEC VP9 Decoder
$ gsettings get org.gnome.Epiphany.web:/org/gnome/epiphany/web/ hardware-acceleration-policy
'always'

If I need to set an environment variable, I am unsure what it may be.
$ VDPAU_DRIVER=nvidia vdpauinfo
display: :0   screen: 0
Error creating VDPAU device: 1

It looks like vdpauinfo does not work under Wayland. But GNOME Web behaves the same under the default Wayland and Xorg sessions.
I tried installing nvidia-vaapi-driver as a translation layer. It seems to work.
$ vainfo 2>/dev/null | egrep -i "driver|VP9"
vainfo: Driver version: VA-API NVDEC driver [direct backend]
      VAProfileVP9Profile0            : VAEntrypointVLD

However, installing gstreamer1.0-vaapi was not enough to utilize it.
$ gst-inspect-1.0 va
Plugin Details:
  Name                     va
  Description              VA-API codecs plugin
  Filename                 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstva.so
  Version                  1.24.8
  License                  LGPL
  Source module            gst-plugins-bad
  Documentation            https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/va/
  Source release date      2024-09-19
  Binary package           GStreamer Bad Plugins (Debian)
  Origin URL               https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/gst-plugins-bad1.0


  0 features:

I also tried ranking a decoder on the command line like this.
$ GST_PLUGIN_FEATURE_RANK=nvvp9dec:MAX epiphany
$ GST_PLUGIN_FEATURE_RANK=avdec_vp9:MAX epiphany

What should I have been doing instead?
After reverting the installation of the nonfree driver (but still with nonfree firmware), Epiphany, Firefox, Totem play the videos smoothly. (Totem even does not require the linked workaround.)
$ vainfo
Trying display: wayland
libva info: VA-API version 1.22.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nouveau_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_22
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.22 (libva 2.22.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Mesa Gallium driver 24.2.4-1 for NV136
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
$ glxinfo | grep renderer
    GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_MESA_gl_interop, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_gl_interop, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, GLX_MESA_swap_control, 
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
OpenGL renderer string: NV136

